# Is it possible to scroll to anchor after external elements are loaded through jQuery.load()?

Tags: javascript, html

The scenario is this:

- Link from an RSS feed into my website `http://website.com/#anchorelement`
- I'd like to jump/scroll to `#anchorelement`

However, `#anchorelement` is loaded using `jQuery.load()` **after** `http://website.com/` is ready. As a result, using the link `http://website.com/#anchorelement` does not jump to `#anchorelement` because the element has yet to be loaded when performing the jump.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make this work? Is it possible to intercept the anchor jump with javascript and make it wait until the `jQuery.load()` call is complete?

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you can pass a callback function as the second argument to `jQuery.load` and it will be executed after completion. edit: you probably need to check `window.location.hash` in the callback, find the matching element and use `element.scrollIntoView()` to scroll,

Comment: Thanks! If I'm understanding correctly, what's happening is that the callback after .load() will grab the .hash from the url and scroll to it after it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  // so this is inside your document ready function.
  // you need to add a callback
  $( somecontainer ).load('somecontent', function(){
    // after the content has been loaded
    // check if a hash is present in the location
    if( window.location.hash != '' ){ 
      // find an element with matching id
      var anchor = $( location.hash ).get(0);
      // if element was found scroll it into view
      if( anchor ){ anchor.scrollIntoView() }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple content to load, load it one per one using callback function and if you want to scroll on one of them, call function scroll on the last callback.

```
$(function ()
{
  //Get the hash and load your content
  var hash = location.hash.replace('#', '');
  loadLocationContent(hash);
});

function loadLocationContent(hash)
{
  $('container1').load("someContent1", function(){
    $('container2').load("someContent2", function(){
      $('container3').load("someContent3", function(){
        $('container4').load("someContent4", scrollToHashAfterContentLoad(hash));
      });
    });  
  });
}

function scrollToHashAfterContentLoad(hash, contentId)
{
  if (hash != '')
  {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#' + hash).offset().top }, 2000);
  }
}
```